# Rails 3 how to display validation errors using JS format (AJAX)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 app I have the following partial to display error messages in the main layout:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I am using JQuery to call create method and created a create.js.erb which is run succesfully after creating the model or after validating with errors.

The question is: how do I go about displaying the list of validation errors in my partial from create.js.erb file? Or ... can that be done from the controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your create.js.erb,

```
<% if @your_variable.errors.count > 0 %> #your_variable is the variable you declared in your controller
  $('.new-user-form').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'form')%>"); # new-user-form is the class name of the div that had the form
<% else %>
  window.location.href='<%= url_for(:action => :index) %>'
<% end %>
```

In this case that your form is a partial with the div like the following:

```
<%= form_for(@your_variable, :remote => true) do >
  ....
<% end %>

<div class="new-user-form"> # In your index or any page that you called that partial
</div>
```

And you need to add `format js` in your create action in the controller

If you provide more code, I can specify the exact thing. It's just an idea for you to do.